# Expose pods in AKS to internet with existing setup

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, azure-aks

We have a request to expose certain pods in an AKS environment to the internet for 3rd party use.

Currently we have a private AKS cluster with a managed standard SKU load balancer in front using the advanced azure networking (basically Calico) where each Pod gets its own private IP from the Vnet IP space. All private IPs currently route through a firewall via user defined route in order to reach the internet, and vice versa. Traffic between on prem routes over a VPN connection through the azure virtual wan. I don’t want to change any existing routing behavior unless 100% necessary.

My question is, how do you expose an existing private AKS cluster’s specific Pods to be accessible from the internet? The entire cluster does not need to be exposed to the internet. The issue I foresee is the ephemeral Pods and ever changing IPs making simple NATing in the firewalls not an option. I’ve also thought about simply making a new AKS cluster with a public load balancer. The issue here though is security as it must still go through the firewalls and likely could with existing user defined routes

What is the recommended way to setup the architecture where certain Pods in AKS can be accessible over the internet, while still allowing those Pods to access the Pods over the private network. I want to avoid exposing all Pods to the internet

Comment: You can expose your deployments, as services, like NodePort or LoadBalancer

Comment: Do you have an example? Not familiar with these or what they do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several years later and wanted to update.

We did successfully implement a scalable ingress option into our private AKS cluster using NGINX as the ingress. The basic flow was

Public IP  > NAT to frontend private IP of NGINX > NGINX path rules that point to your pod/service

Taking a URL as an example for a microservice of [www.example.com/service1](http://www.example.com/service1), the public DNS entry you create is what resolves [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to the public IP that you will NAT to the private IP of NGINX. Then, the rules you create within NGINX take the specific /service1 path of the URL and use it to route to the specific service you pointed it at. It behaves much like URL switching in other load balancers. That is really all NGINX is doing for you. In NGINX syntax, this involves specifying a hosts name (URL) and an associated rule with a backend path and service name. The service name in this example is `service1` and the path is `/` because service1 sits just behind the root.

Something like this saves cost by using less public IPs. For example, you can use a subdomain to easily NAT traffic to a seperate test environment. [www.test.example.com](http://www.test.example.com) and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) can point to separate public IPs, which you can NAT to separate AKS clusters running NGINX. In this way, your NGINX rules can be identical because it's only looking for /service1 which hopefully you've mirrored test and prod environments.

Many ways to do this but a few recommendations from lessons learned

- use subdomains to break out multiple environments
- standardize your NGINX private front end IP across envronments (make them all end in .100 as an example
- create a standard NGINX ingress template where you really only need to modify the serviceName. Your hostName should be static within an environment
- have your devs include this and deploy their microservices with helm rather than relying on an infrastructure team to update NGINX services. Sort of defeats the devops mentality and speed gains

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of options that you can use in order to expose your application to

outside your network, such as: Service:

> - [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport): Exposes the Service on each Node’s IP at a static port (the  `NodePort`). A  `ClusterIP`  Service, to which the  `NodePort`  Service routes, is automatically created. You’ll be able to contact the  `NodePort`  Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting  `<NodeIP>:<NodePort>`.
> - [`LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer): Exposes the Service externally using a cloud provider’s load balancer.  `NodePort`  and  `ClusterIP`  Services, to which the external load balancer routes, are automatically created.

Also, there is another option that is use an **`ingress`**, IMO this is the best way to expose HTTP applications externally, because it's possible to create rules by path and host, and gives you much more flexibility than services. For ingress **only** HTTP/HTTPS is supported, if you need TCP then go to Services

I'd recommend you take a look in this links to understand in deep how services and ingress works:

[Kubernetes Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)

[Kubernetes Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

[NGINX Ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/)

[AKS network concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-network)

Comment: How does that take the necessary NAT into consideration that must take place on the firewall? Do ingress controllers bind a static IP to the desired Pod regardless if the pod changes IPs? These firewalls can also NAT by FQDN of DNS is a possibility

Comment: If you use nginx-ingress, it will create a load balancer and bind the external ip to the nginx-ingress service, they will forward the traffic for the right service, About the nat, your nodes must have access to the internet, so you need to configure the NAT service for all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy nginx ingress controller and bind the ingress controller service to a public Load Balancer. Define Ingress rules for the kubernetes services that you want to access from internet. Note that ingress controller enables entry point to the services running inside kubernetes